# subset vector by first letter in R

Tags: r

I am working in R and I have a character vector. I would like to subset this vector by the first letter of the string of characters. So, for example, how can I subset the vector to return only those elements in the vector that start with the letter A?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use grep:

```
vector = c("apple", "banana", "fox", "Actor")
vector[grep("^[aA].*", vector)]

[1] "apple" "Actor"
```

Comment: Or, in one line: `grep("^[aA].*", vector, value=TRUE)`

Answer (score 7):

You could also use `substr` with `tapply` to get a list of all types:

```
tapply(vector,toupper(substr(vector,1,1)),identity)

$A
[1] "apple" "Actor"

$B
[1] "banana"

$F
[1] "fox"
```

Comment: Or `split(vector,toupper(substr(vector,1,1)))`