# Sorting a filtered TDM matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I got a problem with a TDM matrix - I was able to sort it accordingly, everything went fine there, but no I would like to filter it (or the other way round, I heard, its more efficient to filter a unsorded matrix). Either way, The thing I want to do is filtering the TDM, as in this question: [subset vector by first letter in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724564/subset-vector-by-first-letter-in-r) 
Now the TDM looks like this:

```
> inspect(tdm[1:5,1:10])
<<TermDocumentMatrix (terms: 5, documents: 10)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 3/47
Sparsity           : 94%
Maximal term length: 10
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

            Docs
Terms        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ability    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
  about      0 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 0  0
  acceptance 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
  accepted   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
  access     0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0  0
```

But I would like to filter the Terms with ac and leave only that:

```
            Docs
Terms        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ability    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  0
  about      0 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 0  0
```

I tried to use grep or subset, but couldnt manage to achieve that, but I get the error that there is no such case (named numeric (0)). I'm pretty new to R so please - if I'm searching in the wrong direction, point it out, I'd be really grateful. Big thanks in advance.

The code is pretty straighforward:

```
library("tm")
data(acq)
    corpus<-Corpus(VectorSource(acq))
    tdm<-TermDocumentMatrix(corpus)
    final<-as.matrix(tdm)
    final[grep("^[aA].*", final)]
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It's best to include minimal sample input data in the question itself. Be clear what the desired output is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have edited the Question in accordance to the guidelines. I hope its ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the terms that start with "a" use

```
final[ grep("^[aA].*", rownames(final)) , ]
```

It's the not matrix values themselves that hold the terms, it's the row names of the matrix that have the values you want to grep against. And then since you're subsetting a matrix by rows, you should use the two value `[row,col]` subsetting syntax.